# How to change default volume for Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, boot, audio

I have Linux Mint (with KDE desktop, if it matters) installed on my notebook. Every time when I power it on the volume is set on 100 (maximum level). How can I change this value? Or maybe enable saving volume level at shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changing Volume from CLI

From looking at this [Unix Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118499/change-volume-with-terminal) it looks like there is the `pactl` command that can be used to control the volume, such as:

```
# Increase volume by 50%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +50%

# Decrease volume by 50%
pactl set-sink-volume -- 0 -50%
```

You will need to identify the sink to change the volume for with `pactl list short sinks`.

### Running Command at Boot Time

This command can be added to the crontab so that it is executed at boot time, to do this:

- Open crontab file for editing (this will use the `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` variable if set)

  ```
  crontab -e
  ```
- Add an entry similar to the following (this will take 50% from the volume level at boot time)

  ```
  @reboot        pactl set-sink-volume 0 -50%
  ```